# How to implement rufus-scheduler in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rufus-scheduler

The schedule is running but errors "undefined method 'do_something'". What is not right?

Using rails 3.

In config/initializers/task_scheduler.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'  
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new
scheduler.every("10s") do
    JobThing.do_something
end
```

models/job_thing.rb:
`class JobThing < ActiveRecord::Base
    def do_something
        puts "something"
    end 
end`

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're trying to call a class-level method from the task_scheduler when you've actually defined an instance method in your JobThing class. You can define a class method as below :

```
class JobThing < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.do_something
    puts "something"
  end
end
```